# How to open files for built-in code in IntelliJ-Idea for Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, code-documentation

As an example, if someone wants to see the all the members for the built-in class `Array`, how do I see the file in IntelliJ-IDEA Kotlin without going to [Kotlin's Reference Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays)? Basically, how does someone open `Array`'s source file?

I don't know where to find it in the file explorer pane.

Comment: Do you mean `Control + N`?

Answer (score 0):

The `Declaration or Usages` shortcut, which can be found at the `Keymap` section inside `Settings` and defaults to `Ctrl+B` (or a click while holding `Ctrl`), will do exactly that and, as a bonus, will also find all the usages after you open the source file and try the command once again.